# Duplicate chapter headings show up in Latex

Tags: chapters

I am trying to write a thesis paper in Latex. I've created a document that specifies the chapter heading per chapter. The problem is that the chapter shows up twice per page. For example,

```
\chapter{CHAPTER 1}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
```

Actual:
[image]

Expected:
I expected that the actual head would show the Chapter and then the section after it.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You mention "the actual head would show"... what is this "actual head"? You provided `CHAPTER 1`, which is the "actual head"; so the output is as expected. You're probably looking for `\chapter{INTRODUCTION}`. Or, better yet, `\chapter[Introduction]{INTRODUCTION}` if you don't want a capitalized title in the ToC.

Answer (score 1):

The chapter title is supposed to be the subject like `\chapter{Introduction}` the duplicated wording you see for chapter you would see also for `\section` if you used `\section{1.1}` which would be the equivalent usage here.